# C++ argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type void (__cdecl*)(void), when calling std::atexit()

Tags: c++, std

While using certain C++ libraries, I've often come across functions with parameters requiring pointers to functions. This implies methods won't be accepted.

Such as std's `atexit(void (__cdecl*)(void));`

In this case, it's very inconvenient to call such function from a class, when you'd like to pass the functionality from a method.

I know of these two workarounds, but they have drawbacks/seem impossible:

- Declaring the method as static: Means that method can't call any
  other non-static methods from the same class.
- Passing an actual function: Is an absolute mess, and may require all
  sorts of black magic to get the propper functionality to execute
  within the method.

What other workarounds are there for these situations in general? Or at least for calling the atexit() example from a class where a method would be ideal as exit function.

Comment: class methods can only be called on an object,  but there is no object in sight here ... it's not clear what you intend.  You could make a free function that calls a method on an object, of course you need to ensure the object still exists at the point the function is invoked (i.e. it should be a static storage duration object)

Comment: There are only 3 ways to use a class method where a C-style function pointer is expected. You already know 2 of them: 1) declare the class method as `static`. 2) use a free-standing function that calls the method. 3) wrap the method call inside of a thunk. For #1 and #2, if you need access to the object then you have to pass it in a user-defined callback parameter if available, otherwise store it in global/threadlocal memory. For #3, the object (or at least a pointer to it) can be stored inside the thunk itself.

Answer (score 0):

`atexit` functions are called on program exit, in reverse order. Local static object destructors are also called at this point. So in this example:

```
void f()
{
  static X x;
  atexit(f1);
  static Y y;
}
```

On first call `x` and `y` destructor would be registered to be called on program exit, and `f1()` would be called between `y.Y::~Y()` and `x.X::~X()`.

So if you create a collection of `std::function` objects to be called on destruction of the collection, that may be a viable workaround.

It still may not work well for multiple functions, as all would be called in a single loop, instead of LIFO order relative to other static destructor / atexit call.

---

Another option could be to look at `at_thread_exit`. It has different semantic, but may suit your needs as well.

---

Thunk, mentioned by @Remy Lebeau, could be the best workaround. But it may be nontrivial to implement, that's why I suggest considering other workarounds as well.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. I'll be exploring them all in order to find the best solution.